# Importing shell script function

Tags: bash, shell

I have a function `err()` in file `abc`. The files do not have a `.sh` extension, but they start with `#!/bin/bash`.

```
err () {
    echo "${1}" >&2 
}
```

Now I am importing it in a different file `xyz`:

```
source abc
someFunction(){ 
    err "Failed to back up"
}
```

Is this the right way of importing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can do like you mentioned above or like: `. FILENAME`

The file need not to end with `.sh`

Answer (score 5):

That's fine, here are some more hints:

1. Use a naming convention for functions, for example prefix the function name with `f_`, for example `f_err`.  Function calls appear no different as other commands, this is a hint to the reader.  It also reduces the chances of a name collision.
2. You need read access only, and you do not need the `#!/bin/bash` (its just a comment).
3. In Bash, some options have to be set before function parsing.  For example, `shopt -s extglob` has to be done before and outside the function if it uses extended globbing.  Putting that inside the function is too late.
4. Bash does not support the FPATH environment variable or autoload (as Korn shell does).

Answer (score 3):

You need to *export* newly created functions

at end of `abc` add this:

```
export -f err
```

Comment: You only need to export the function to make it available in a subshell (one started by running another instance of bash). After sourcing the file, any functions defined therein will be available in the current shell.